# "Permissions" needed taking website data then sending form to another website

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Having an extension that takes data from Gmail, then sends information to another site like `example.com`.

Which permissions should I specify in the manifest file?

(extension actually works in Chrome without specifying them)

Which should be the equivalent action in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions in Chrome would be:

```json
"permissions": [
  "https://mail.google.com/*", "*://example.com/*"
]
```

This makes sure that you can access both sites. As to Firefox, you don't have to specify anything - Firefox extensions always have access to all websites.

Comment: @jacktrades: When you inject a content script into a page it is bound by the same-origin policy - a content script in `mail.google.com` isn't allowed to access `apis.google.com` frame. If you need data from the `apis.google.com` frame then you should add that site to permissions and inject your content script into this frame directly.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do inject that content script directly in my specific case? It's tricky because I'm executing the script from an iframe (canvas) that appears to contain the data I need. Still confused, please see my other question.